Spring JPA one to many relationship returning a null
I have a service class that persists an object.but whn i call the relationship it returns null..
Author class
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Book> books;

Book class
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false)
private Author author;

now in my create service class i create an author and and save it as follows
    Author a = authorRepo.saveAndFlush(authorObj);
    syncService.sync(a);

And in my other SyncService, I make this call:
a.getBooks().stream.....

its this a.getBooks that throws a null pointer exception,I was under the impression that JPa would return an empty collection if no objects exist?
I also seem to notice that if i save a book entity with the values of author. Then when i fetch the author in the same call the books are not associated with the author.

did you tried private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>(); ?

@YoucefLAIDANI I tried that, which worked.. but the issue im having now is that when I update and add a book to the author. When i then go to the author and do a getBooks.. in the same request..  i dont get the get books .. but wortks fine when the ui gets response and makes another second call. Is that some cascading issue there.

Try to remove the lazy loading

If calling a.getBooks() results in a NullPointerException, then a is nulll. If you meant that a.getBooks().stream() throws a NullPointerException, then it means that your books list is indeed null. If your a entity is attached to a persistence context, then calling a.getBooks() will always return you an object of type PersistentBag, which implements the list in the persistence context. However, if you get a NullPointerException when calling a.getBooks().stream(), then your a entity is not attached to a persistence context and is in a transient state. You need to look for a bug in your sync() method. It is quite possible that the NullPointerException is thrown for some other reason.
